# FAISS-GPU cannot be used with GPU version 30xx

Tags: python, python-3.x, gpu, nvidia, faiss

I'm writing Python source code and using Faiss. I can use Faiss on CPU, 20xx GPU eg: RTX 2080Ti,... However, when I run on devices like RTX 3060, RTX 3070, the system freezes and I can't kill the program by Ctrl + C.
Here is the source code I use: https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/blob/main/tutorial/python/5-Multiple-GPUs.py

If anyone has encountered this error and successfully fixed it, please share how to do it with me.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Faiss version: release 1.7.1

Running on: GPU + Python

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I used Anaconda, I installed bellow, it worked. If you use Docker, please install Miniconda.

`conda install faiss-gpu cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch-gpu`

`conda install -c anaconda pytorch-gpu`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).